# Where I can take correct API token for requests to Trello behalf on user (ruby-trello)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, rails-api, trello

I am using Ruby on Rails 5.2 and gems: ruby-trello, devise, omniauth-trello.

I want to make authorized requests on behalf of Trello user same as shows here: https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello#multiple-users

Example from git docs:

```
@client_bob = Trello::Client.new(
  :consumer_key => YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY,
  :consumer_secret => YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  :oauth_token => "Bob's access token",
  :oauth_token_secret => "Bob's access secret"
)
```

My steps:

1. User (Bob) sign in with Trello and get his own oauth_secret and oauth_token
2. App creates a Trello::Client for Bob using:

   - his own oauth data (:oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret)
   - I got consumer_key from here: https://trello.com/app-key (in the top of page, first block with key field)
   - consumer_secret was taken from https://trello.com/app-key too, but from the bottom of page, last block with key secret

After this, I'm trying to get any data from Bob's trello account (boards, lists, tasks etc.) but always getting 500 error (invalid token).

Could you explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was implementing a session controller to request and authorize access to user's trello and then call `Trello::Client` with the authorization params inside the callback method on the controller.

Check out this:[Trello OAuth 1.0 authorization with Ruby](https://gist.github.com/eddygarcas/4b52e588c90e38c9fa944dfe0cb2840d)

Then inside the authorization method you can call `Trello::Client` using `:oauth_token` and `:oauth_token_secret` from get_access_token call or store them both on the session object and use them anywhere.